# How does expand and collapse work on w3.org?

Tags: javascript, html, css

See this list  [w3.org expand and collapse](http://www.w3.org/2002/03/tutorials.html#webdesign_htmlcss), How do they do the expand and collapse magic here?

I know how to do this using javascript but it seems they didn't use javascript, at least not from what I have observed..

Comment: You have observed wrong, they add and remove a class called "closed." If you inspect element on any of them then open and close the list, you'll see it.

Comment: I have seen it already.. just couldn't figure it out where the toggle related code was so I simply conclude that they didn't use javascript... @lan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you say they are not using javascript, right click the page in chrome, select view source and scroll to the bottom , you will see this :-

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/2008/site/js/main" xml:space="preserve"><!-- --></script>
```

Also notice each div has an assigned id which may be used to point to each element uniquely in JS and which signals that they infact are using JS for these effects.

Comment: Can you point out which code segment they are using specifically? I simply can't figure it out. I know that they included some js files, but I don't see which part of the script did the expand/collapse trick.

Comment: That might not be possible, they are using a external JS file and have not typed the code directly into the webpage. The external file seems to be Obfuscated (minimised-which means reduced in size with whitespaces removed and variables renamed to make it non-user readable). Here is the link to the JS file http://www.w3.org/2008/site/js/main , I could not hope you can make out from it.

Comment: BTW its no magic to expand and collapse elements, its simple Javascript events and modifying display properties of elements, For better understanding see various js tutorials available on this like http://www.ehow.com/how_8594746_expand-section-javascript.html